# subtract two numbers in the same window

Tags: tableau-api

is there a window calculation that I can use to find the year over year difference in sales?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a new dimension using the 'Lookup' window function.

1. Right-click on the Data pane and choose 'Create Calculated Field'
2. Name your calculated field (for example, 'YOY Diff')
3. Enter the following formula:

   **(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Sales])),0) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Sales])),-1))/ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Sales])),-1))**
4. Save the calculated field. Right click and select 'Compute Using' = [Date] field and choose the 'Year' option
5. Save the calculated field and drag it into the Columns bar at the top next to the 'Year' dimension

This should add a column to your table next to each year with that year's 'YOY Diff' for each corresponding month.

Here's a quick explanation of the calculated field formula:

- The LOOKUP window function takes the format LOOKUP(expression, [offset]) and returns the value of the expression with an offset relative to the current row. In this case, our expression is SUM[Sales], so we look at the current value (say, 2018) - the previous value (2017) and divide that difference by the previous value (2017).
- The ZN function replaces NULL values with zeroes to avoid errors.
- The ABS function ensures the % difference will be positive.

Comment: this was a really amazing response. Thanks so much for taking the time to go through it all. Have a wonderful week

Comment: This answer is correct and useful, but there is a short cut to get the same effect with less effort. Take your original view, with SUM(Sales) on the text shelf, i.e. on the marks card with a text T icon to its left. Right click on that SUM(Sales) pill and choose Quick Table Calc -> Percent Difference. Right click again and you can set the "Relative To" and "Compute Using" settings to behave as desired if the defaults don't give you what you want.  Read about table calcs in the on line help for details